# Using htmlspecialchars() with a textbox

Tags: php, jquery, htmlspecialchars

I have a textbox with user input on page 1. Its content is stored in a Session variable on page 2. Now, I want to add a "Back" button on page 2. Do I have to use htmlspecialchars() before inserting the Session variable back in the textbox? If yes, what do I have to do with " or ' inputs? I guess html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars($text)) does not make sense, does it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT:

Back on page 1 I use jQuery to fill in the textbox. Currently I use

```
var usertext = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['text'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>;
$('#textbox').val(usertext);
```

By doing this I unfortunately don't get the exact User input back (if characters like " or ' are inserted by the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to use htmlspecialchars() before inserting the Session variable back in the textbox?

If you want to insert into a textbox with jQuery, you need to store the value within the page somewhere. e.g.

```
<body data-text-value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['text']) ?>">
```

Then to insert it into your text box using jQuery:

```
$('#textbox').val($('body').data('text-value'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I edited my question above. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: No, you can only use `htmlspecialchars` for insertion in html, not Javascript.

Comment: So, then I would just do this?

    var usertext = <?php echo $_SESSION['text']; ?>;
    $('#textbox').val(usertext);

Is this safe? Thank you again.

Comment: `<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['text']) ?>" />`

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it with Javascript.

Comment: I don't fully understand why you cannot insert directly into the page HTML, however I have updated my answer for how to do this securely.

Comment: I need jQuery because my input fields are generated dynamically. I store my Session variables in hidden input fields (which are not generated dynamically) now and htmlspecialchars works fine. Thanks a lot for this advice.